# A:hover doesnt work, i screwed something up

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>
         (Test)
       </title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
a:wrapper {background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#FF8347; text-align:center; padding:0px; text-decoration:none; font-size:40px; display:inline-block; width:192px; border-radius:0x; -moz-border-radius:0px; -webkit-border:0px;}
body{margin:0 auto; width:2500px; position;relative;}
div.navMENU{ width:100%; height:200px;}
div.navMENU ul{list-style-type:none; padding:0px; margin:0 auto;}
div.navMENU li{float:left; padding:0px; margin:0px;}
div.navMENU a{display:inline-block; width:192px; border-radius:0x; -moz-border-radius:0px; -webkit-border:0px; background-color:#777580; color:#FF7533; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; font-size:40px;}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="navMENU"
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a> </li>
    <li><a href=""> 2</a> </li>
    <li><a href=""> 3</a> </li>
    <li><a href=""> 4</a> </li>
    <li><a href=""> 5</a> </li>
    <li><a href=""> 6</a> </li>
    <li><a href=""> 7</a> </li>
    <li><a href=""> 8</a> </li>
    <li><a href=""> 9</a> </li>
    <li><a href=""> 10</a> </li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

A:hover doesnt work, how can i fix it?
the home.html file isnt needed i think, tell me if u need it to be able to help me.
What did I do wrong?

detail
details
detail needed
i needed so much detail
site told me to add more detail

Comment: What's "a:wrapper"? Was that supposed to be hover? And why does <div class="navMENU" have no closing ">"  ?

Comment: You also have one extra `</head>`.

Comment: it is hover not wrapper. and close the div with class ="navMENU" and remove the second closing head tag.

Comment: Use Html Tidy. On mobile now can't put link.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you wrote `a:wrapper` instead of `a:hover`.

There are other issues as well, for instance you have one surplus `</head>`, I guess `-webkit-border:0px;` should be `-webkit-border-radius: 0px;` (2X), `position;relative;` should be `position: relative;` (with a colon) and `<div class="navMENU"` is missing a closing `>` and a closing `</div>` tag.

So, if I may say so, your code is a bit sloppy. Your current issue and those issues that may follow are likely due to such errors, and it's a good idea to closely inspect your code for errors. Make sure to use the [W3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/) and use an editor with proper syntax highlighting to help you spot those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `:wrapper` and add `:hover` it will work

Below is the snippet check that out..

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 2500px;
  position;
  relative;
}
div.navMENU {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
div.navMENU ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div.navMENU li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
div.navMENU a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 192px;
  border-radius: 0x;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border: 0px;
  background-color: #777580;
  color: #FF7533;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 40px;
}
div.navMENU a:hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #FF8347;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 192px;
  border-radius: 0x;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border: 0px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navMENU">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href=""> 2</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href=""> 3</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href=""> 4</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href=""> 5</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href=""> 6</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href=""> 7</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href=""> 8</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href=""> 9</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href=""> 10</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```